# how to fix a illustrator .jpeg file from being blurry?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I am making my son's birthday invitation on illustrator. It looks perfectly fine until I save it for web so it will be a .jpeg so I can print it. Once it is a .jpeg it looks blurry. I am planing to print this like a photo. I have made things like this before just never ran in to a problem like this. How do I fix this so when they are printed it, it will be clear?

[image: planing to print like a photo.]

Just scared they will come out blurry when I print.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've kinda stated the answer in your question. If you are **printing** the invitation, "saving for web" is not what you want. To re-state the obvious, that command is for saving files for web use, not print. :)

If you need a jpeg for printing purposes, use the File > Export command in Illustrator. After choosing where to save the file, you'll get a dialog box called "JPEG Options"... here you'll want to use "CMYK" and "High/300 ppi" settings.

The one caveat here is that this will only work if your photo was hi-res in the first place. If it's a low resolution photo, no settings you choose will "un-blur" it for you.

Answer (score -2):

**Is Opening The AI File In Photoshop Old School?**

I never exported from Illustrator but rather opened the AI in Photoshop. I started doing this a long time ago and haven't looked back.

There are a few things you need to do, like embed linked images, but it's worth the control in my opinion.

Comment: How does this solve the given question?

Comment: If a person is saving an image such as this for printing purposes, I am making the assumption they'll save it to disk and upload to Snapfish or take to their local Walgreens to print it like a picture. Opening the file in Photoshop prompts a person for desired resolution, thus likely solving the blurry issue.