# Blurry Image/Logo exported as jpeg from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, jpg

When I export my image as a jpeg from Illustrator the extension is blurry. How do I save to jpeg to get a clear image?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix a illustrator .jpeg file from being blurry?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50731/how-to-fix-a-illustrator-jpeg-file-from-being-blurry)

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Could you share one of the jpegs you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

it could be that you're trying to save it too big and the image isnt a vector? otherwise i'd advise to save it as an AI file and drag that file into your Photoshop and export it there if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other replies about optimising a .jpeg - as you're exporting from Illustrator I presume you are looking to save a vector artwork as a raster file (i.e. an image made up of pixels).

It may be worth saving the image as a .png rather than a .jpeg as the jpeg is designed specifically for photographs, rather than images with large areas of flat colour (which png is more appropriate for). You can save as a png from the 'File -
Export As' menu. They are widely supported in web and print like the .jpeg is.